# JAVA XML find node without knowing parent

Tags: java, xml, xpath

JAVA & XML

I have an xml document like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<elezione>
  <codice>6</codice>
  <descrizione>EUROPEE</descrizione>
  <data>25 MAGGIO 2014</data>
  <enti-partecipanti>
    <italia>
      <circ-europea>
        <codice>2</codice>
        <nome>II : ITALIA NORD-ORIENTALE</nome>
        <regione> ..... </regione>
        <regione> ..... </regione>
        <regione>
          <codice>4</codice>
          <nome>TRENTINO-ALTO ADIGE</nome>
          <provincia> 
            <codice>14</codice>
            <nome>BOLZANO</nome>
            .. Whole load of sub nodes and stuff
          </provincia>
          <provincia> 
            <codice>14</codice>
            <nome>BOLZANO</nome>
            .. Whole load of sub nodes and stuff
          </provincia>
          ..
          ..
        </regione>
        <regione> ... </regionr>
      </circ-europea>
    </italia>
  </enti-partecipanti>
</elezione>
```

I need to start examining from the `<regione>` node with "codice" = 14

Unfortunately the structure ABOVE the list of "`<regione>`" nodes changes continuously (the supplier of the xml is pretty CRAZY), but below that node, things are pretty standard.

Currently I'm using classic "DocumentBuilder ... " code.

The main problem is that I start my search for regione starting INSIDE the `<elezione>` node, and not from the document itself, so I don't know how to use xPath starting from a node instead of a document!

Comment: Did you try "regione//codice"?

Comment: What is your XPath, and where did you call it?

Comment: //regione/provincia/codice[text()='14'] gives you all codices that have value 14

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a xpath starting with "//".

"//regione" will match all the "regione" nodes.

Comment: OK, I got that far, and I've got a list of "regione" nodes. How do I check the "codice" value?  nodes[i],getElementById("codice").item(0).getTextContent() isn't working ! :( ... Sorry but I'm new to this! ..... BTW, how to you put CR/LF in comments??